# D3 Bar Chart Troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, d3.js

I have a database with 5 columns, ID, customerName, dateYear, dateMonth, and dateDay. The date columns are added into the database when the user sends the form. So for example if a user sent the form today the 3 columns would have 2016, June, and 7. I want to make a D3 bar chart that can pull this information and display how many forms were sent each month/year. I have a list of checkboxes in HTML for the admin to select one or more months, and a year.

```
        <input type="submit" name="monthlyReport" value="Generate a Monthly Report for:" />
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="January" name="monthList[]"/>January
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="February" name="monthList[]"/>February
```

etc...

```
<select name="selyear1">
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
</select>
```

Here is my PHP code that takes the user input and turns it into a query:

```
$monthList = array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
$yearList = array("2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020");

$monthlyReport = isset($_POST["monthlyReport"]) ? $_POST["monthlyReport"] : "";
$monthList = array();
$monthList = isset($_POST["monthList"]) ? $_POST["monthList"] : "";
$selectedYear = isset($_POST["selyear1"]) ? $_POST["selyear1"] : "";
if(isset($monthlyReport) && !empty($monthList) && in_array($selectedYear, $yearList)) {
    foreach ($monthList as $month){ 
        if (in_array($month, $monthList)) {

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT dateYear, dateMonth FROM just_ink WHERE dateMonth = :month AND dateYear= :year");
            $stmt->execute(array(":month" => $month, ":year"=> $selectedYear));
            $result[] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        }
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

$result will dump this:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["dateYear"]=> string(4) "2016" ["dateMonth"]=> string(7) "January" } } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["dateYear"]=> string(4) "2016" ["dateMonth"]=> string(4) "June" } [1]=> array(2) { ["dateYear"]=> string(4) "2016" ["dateMonth"]=> string(4) "June" } } }
```

So how exactly do I turn this result into the D3 bar chart? I've look at the d3Noob tips and tricks but this is a more advanced case I believe. Thanks ahead of time for the responses!

Comment: What is the value you want to graph? Im not able to see it within your dump

Comment: @torresomar For example, if I have 2 rows of that contain "June" I want the bar to have an X value of "June" and a Y value of "2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you create an array with the desired values.

```
$array = array( array("2016", "January"),
                array("2016", "February"),
                array("2016", "February"),
                array("2016", "February"),
                array("2016", "March"),
                array("2016", "March"),
                array("2016", "June"),
                array("2016", "June")
              );

echo json_encode($array);
//[["2016","January"],["2016","February"],["2016","February"],["2016","February"],["2016","March"],["2016","March"],["2016","June"],["2016","June"]]
```

I would expose an endpoint which would return this `json` and then use it within my script, so you may be able to make an async call and don't stop the rendering of your page in order to fetch/wait for data.

If we use the json returned by the previous snippet we can call `d3.json` and modify the data in order to create a bar chart.

```
d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
  var nested_data = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d[1];
    })
    .rollup(function(leaves) {
      return leaves.length;
    })
    .entries(data);
    console.log(nested_data);
    //Object {key: "January", values: 1}
    //Object {key: "February", values: 3}
    //Object {key: "March", values: 2}
    //Object {key: "June", values: 2}


  x.domain(nested_data.map(function(d) { // Set x domain by keys (Month Name)
    return d.key;
  }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(nested_data, function(d) { // Set y domain by finding max value (Month count)
    return d.values;
  })]);

  svg.append("g") // Append x-axis
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g") // Append y-axis
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Frequency");

  svg.selectAll(".bar") // Join our data
    .data(nested_data) 
    .enter() // For each value do the following
    .append("rect") 
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.key);
    })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.values);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.values);
    });
}
```

You can find a working plnkr with the code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Jin12g7dVdCq2eu46FnX?p=preview